# R: Why does step function of a Linear Modegives different AIC/BIC than AIC function?

Tags: r, aic, stepwise-regression

I don't understand what I make or think wrong, but if one tries to evaluate
the linear model of the data (which you can find in R in the Package AIC(stats)), then

```
     >lm1 <- lm(Fertility ~ . , data = swiss)
     >AIC(lm1)
```

it gives

```
      326.0716
```

If I use step function on this model

```
     >step(lm1)
     Start:  AIC=190.69
     Fertility ~ Agriculture + Examination + Education + Catholic + 
     Infant.Mortality

                        Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
     - Examination       1     53.03 2158.1 189.86
     <none>                          2105.0 190.69
     - Agriculture       1    307.72 2412.8 195.10
     - Infant.Mortality  1    408.75 2513.8 197.03
     - Catholic          1    447.71 2552.8 197.75
     - Education         1   1162.56 3267.6 209.36

     Step:  AIC=189.86
     Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + Infant.Mortality

                        Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
     <none>                          2158.1 189.86
     - Agriculture       1    264.18 2422.2 193.29
     - Infant.Mortality  1    409.81 2567.9 196.03
     - Catholic          1    956.57 3114.6 205.10
     - Education         1   2249.97 4408.0 221.43

     Call:
     lm(formula = Fertility ~ Agriculture + Education + Catholic + 
         Infant.Mortality, data = swiss)

     Coefficients:
          (Intercept)       Agriculture         Education          Catholic                    Infant.Mortality  
              62.1013           -0.1546           -0.9803            0.1247                     1.0784
```

Why are the AIC of the lm1 model and the AIC of the "starting" model of AIC so completely different? Shouldn't they actually be the same, as this step function starts from the full model?

Comment: My guess it's that there's just a constant missing, a constant which is unimportant as far as comparisons go (since it's common for all models). For example, AIC is $-2\ln L+2k$, but in regression models you often see $n\log(s^2)+2k$, which is what you get under normality, apart from a constant.